# Could not create a Disk Cache Sub-directory for the Application Pool

Tags: c#, iis, asp-classic

I'm trying to run an old project using **ASP Classic** with **Visual Studio 2017**. When I hit the run button it send me to *localhost:80xx* and I got this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.

So, manually I change the URL to localhost:80xx/Default.asp and the page didn't change but I got this error on Event Viewer:

> Error: The Template Persistent Cache initialization failed for
>   Application Pool 'MyAppPool' because of the following
>   error: Could not create a Disk Cache Sub-directory for the Application
>   Pool. The data may have additional error codes.

I've already tried the steps below:

1. Added the site to the IIS (7.5) following normal procedure.
2. Installed the ASP role following steps: Control Panel\All Control
       Panel Items\Programs and Features --> Turn Windows on/off --> IIS
       --> Application Development Features --> check "ASP" then click ok.
3. For the ASP option in IIS set the following to "true":  Enable
       client side debugging, Enable server side debugging, Send errors to
       browser, Enable parent path.
4. Created a new application pool with following settings: (.Net
       Framework version: No Managed Code), (Enable 32 bit applications:
       True), (Managed pipelijne mode: Classic)
5. Related this new application pool to the site configured.

The problem persists, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You probably have a corrupt IIS installation, https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213936365-Internal-Server-Error-Could-not-create-a-Disk-Cache-Sub-directory-for-the-Application-Pool

Comment: I agree with lex. It seems that your IIS permission or something else has been corrupted. Please try to reinstall IIS completely or try to use process monitor to monitor and correct permission.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Might be useful - [Classic asp "An error occurred when verifying security for the message." iis7 transport level security](//stackoverflow.com/a/7008146) *(talks about setting permissions for the Template directory)*.